# Access WebSocketConfigurer with Grails 3 spring-websocket

Tags: grails, websocket, spring-websocket, grails-3.0

I'm trying to register a WebsocketHandler in a **Grails 3.2.x** app with the **spring-websocket** plugin.

I tried creating a custom websocketConfig with the `grails create-web-socket-config` command, but the resulting class does not implement `org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketConfigurer` to be able to add handlers to with the `registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry)` event.

How would I be able to do this within an `AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

within an `AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer`, you wont be able to do that.

but you should be able to just supply another `@EnableWebSocket` annotated `@Configuration` bean implementing `WebSocketConfigurer` that is picked up by component scan or you register it manually in `resources.groovy`.

ref. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-server-handler